# Limit Parallel.ForEach to only 64 actions

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have the following code to insert data into an excel file:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(fileNames.ToArray(), filename =>
 {
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connect to filename.xlsx)
    cn.open()
    ... oledb stuff...
    cn.close()
 });
```

The problem with this is that OleDbConnection seems to allow only 64 open connections and in this Parallel.ForEach has 300 loops. So an error is thrown by the OledbConnection since there are more than 64 connections open

Is there a work around so that TPL can execute the code only 64 times and queue the rest? Sort of like a batch of 64

Comment: Use the ParallelSettings class.

Comment: Use the Options with MaxDegereeOfparallelism=32. You need some elbow room. And maybe even lower, in the background this is all I/O on a single file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

```
        ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
        parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 64;
```

and use 'parallelOptions' calling 'Parallel.ForEach'

So your code will look like

```
Parallel.ForEach(fileNames.ToArray(), parallelOptions , filename =>
.
.
```